# Is 80% of childs intelligence acquired from mother?

Tags: intelligence, genetics, parenting

Several articles on internet claim that 80% of child's intelligence is acquired from mother. however not providing any scientific publications. Is it really true?

source: http://brooklynmutt.com/post/158024942/medical-evidence-shows-that-approximately-80-of-a

Comment: There is research on hereditary theory of intelligence by Professor Gillian Turner published in Lancet-http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/myl/llog/Turner1996.pdf on this subject but the 80 percent figure is not backed up by reliable sources as mentioned here in point #4-http://factually.gizmodo.com/uberfacts-is-still-full-of-lies-1664836449